# References & Online Resources for C++ Intrinsics of AVX type

Tags: c++, gcc, intrinsics

Can you give me a direction to any site covering information about intrinsics? I searched many sites but they are listing only names. Searched assembly sites but they have only assembly instructions(very similar names but no exact) What I need is something like:

```
 GCC(g++) Intrinsics for x64
          ║
          ║
          ╚══╦═════════╡ Comparison functions
             ║
             ║
             ╠═════════╡ Special functions
             ║
             ║
             ╠══════╦══╡ Arithmetic functions
             ║      ║
             ║      ║
             ║      ║
             ║      ╠════╡ _mm256_mul_ps (selecting this opens an explanation)
             ║      ║

 _mm256_mul_ps: Multiplication of float32 vectors. Takes two __m256 arguments,
                multiplies those vectors and returns __m256 type.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel's reference has what are are looking for, I think:

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/index.htm#intref_cls/common/intref_avx_mul_ps.htm

A more up-to-date list is included in the manual for 2013 version of the Intel compiler:

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/hh_goto.htm#GUID-712779D8-D085-4464-9662-B630681F16F1.htm

Comment: Note that those are the instructions for `icc`, not `gcc` as you said you were using.

Comment: So they emmit wrong instructions when I compile ?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Most likely, if they compile, they'll be fine. (GCC could be trying to track ICC here);

Comment: @Billy: The SSE/AVX/etc. intrinsics are generally supported by the Intel, Microsoft, and GCC compilers. (At least, they aim to be compatible in my experience.)

Comment: I know very few intrinsic functions. I used some to make a small vector multiplication. Compiled fine, linked to java through jni. No problem. I got the results but I know only 7-8 functions like these. Im on fx8150 by the way. I need to learn as many as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Intrinsics are not part of the C++ language. If you want the intrinsics provided by your compiler, consult the documentation for your compiler.

For instance, the Visual Studio intrinsics are available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Im using latest version of gcc. Thank you.